# can i save colab project on google drive and upload and start later?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, google-chrome, google-colaboratory

I use `colab.research.google.com` for my research in university, but
unfortunately it erasing all my files daily.

Yesterday I spent  all day for coding, compiling and now I lost all my results...

I want to get some stuff for get the changes from `co-laboratory`
machine (make dump of all file info before work and after work, then
download the changes) then, when I need ma project again - I just want
to upload the changes to `co-laboratory` and then start my project

Answer (score 2):

VMs are indeed ephemeral. A typical pattern is to store persistent files in Google Drive by mounting your Drive filesystem.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

Then, files that you save to `/content/drive` will persist in Drive, and you can access Drive files on that path as well.

More info:
https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=u22w3BFiOveA